# What does any[]=[] datatype mean in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, any

I'm working on a project in a company and there's a variable declared like this

```
  chainTypeList: any[]=[];
```

and I'm not able to access it's values like this.

```
this.chainTypeList.chainTypeCode;
```

It shows this error : **Property 'chainTypeCode' does not exist on type 'any[]'.**

Comment: Why do you think there's a property called `chainTypeCode` on an ___array___?

Comment: Looks more like Typescript, declaring an array of any type, any[], and then assigning an empty array = []

Comment: `chainTypeList` is an array of, presumably, chain types. `: any[]` is TypeScript. Initially it's empty, `= []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is looks like [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s typing.

This means that this is an array of `any` value. An it's `initilized` as an empty one.

The `any` value literally means that you can push any `value` and `value type` into this array.

You can't access it by using this:

```
this.chainTypeList.chainTypeCode;
```

because it's an array and not an object. That's why you get the error:

> Property 'chainTypeCode' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

It should only be something like this:

```
this.chainTypeList
```

or

```
this.chainTypeList[0]
```

If you want a specific position of the array. Just `change the number` for the position you want to obtain.

Comment: You can['t] access it by using this:

Comment: I don't get the comment. Sorry. Can you repeat please?

Comment: You can not access it by using this:

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> `chainTypeList: any[]=[];`

It is written as TypeScript not JavaScript. You cannot do this if it is pure JavaScript. It means that variable `chainTypeList` is declared as an array type `any` (can be any type), which is initialized as an empty array.

and by calling

> `this.chainTypeList.chainTypeCode;`

you are trying to access property named `chainTypeCode` in the object `chainTypeList`. However, the program will not be able to find such property because, as it is declared earlier, the variable is an empty array. It does not have the property you are looking for hence the error

> **Property 'chainTypeCode' does not exist on type 'any[]'.**

Answer (score 0):

> What does any[]=[] datatype mean in TypeScript?

It's not a datatype.

The `any[]` part is a datatype. The `= []` part is called an "assignment". An assignment binds a value to a name, e.g. in this case, it binds the value `[]` (an empty array) to the name `chainTypeList`, meaning that from this point on, dereferencing the name `chainTypeList` will evaluate to an empty array.

> ```
> this.chainTypeList.chainTypeCode;
> ```
>
> It shows this error : **Property 'chainTypeCode' does not exist on type 'any[]'.**

[Arrays don't have a property called `chainTypeCode`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-objects), so the error is correct.